# How does "wrapping" inside objects in JavaScript work exactly?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm not very comfortable with objects yet and this is my first Stack Overflow question so bear with me. Using the following code,

```
function wrap(value) {
   return {
     "value": value
   };
}
var obj = new wrap("Hello");
```

`obj.value` equals "Hello".

Why does this work? It looks to me as if `wrap()` is returning an object not associated with the variable `obj`, so `obj.value` should not equal `Hello`.

How is the object that is returned assigned to the variable `obj`? Does `obj` automatically equal `{"value": value}` because it is wrapped inside `wrap()`?

Comment: you don't need to use `new ` when `return`ing a literal. obj will be whatever the function returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `new` [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) does two things:

1. Binds `this` to a new, empty object
2. Returns `this` at the end of the function if no return statement is reached (as opposed to `undefined`)

But your function has a return statement, which returns the object `{ value: value }`, so you will get that object. This is the same as if you called `var obj = wrap("Hello");`.

To show the significance of `new`, if your function was:

```
function wrap (value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

calling `var obj = new wrap("Hello")` would give the same result (an object with the key `value` storing `"Hello"`), while calling `var obj = wrap("Hello")` would store "Hello" in the key `value` on the global context (the window, in the browser) and `undefined` in the variable `obj`.

Answer (score 4):

You are essentially doing the same thing as

```
var obj = {value: "Hello"};
```

In which case, the following is true

```
obj.value == "Hello"
```

The fact that you're assigning through a function doesn't change anything in this example.

Comment: Whoa whoa, absolutely false. "The fact that you're assigning through a function doesn't change anything" It changes EVERYTHING! the scope of this changes. The execution context changes. Hoisted variables aren't available. "new" has behavior with function constructors that isn't immediately apparent here (although straightforward in this exact use case). I personally think this answer is dangerously naive.

Comment: @rockerest:  well, it changes everything that's not germane to the topic; context doesn't matter, hoisting effects are N/A, and "new" does nothing in this case (due to a non-intrinsic return).

Comment: Well said @dandavis.  Also, great use of the word "germane"!  :)

Comment: The point is that this answer is dangerously naive. Sure, if the OP is doing *exactly this* in their code, no big deal. But answers should address underlying causes and issues. Saying things like "doesn't change anything" sets a dangerous precedent that those words would remain true, which - in a large majority of cases - they won't. This is especially true in this particular scenario where the OP has already stated they're not comfortable with the concept. Reassuring that everything is fine while leaving out all the common gotchas is naive at best and borderline sadistic at worst.

Comment: good teachers know how to effectively communicate the "big idea" without confounding.

Answer (score 0):

when you call function using `new` keyword `this` is returned unless returned value is specefied like your code:

so

```
var obj = new wrap("Hello");
```

will get the value of:

```
 {
 "value": "Hello"
 };
```

because it is passed as an argument so:

```
obj.value=="hello" //true
```

Answer (score 0):

you trait warp() as type (class) and you instantiate an object by new key work 
but you return object

you create object of wrap() with new keyword but you return object of value;

try:

```
function foo( value ) { 
  function bar( x,y ) { return x+y; }
  return  { sum: bar, value: value }  
}


var obj = new foo("hello");
obj.value == "hello" // true 
obj.sum(3,4) // == 7
```

your object can still referring to the inner wrap() with new key word

Comment: if you return from the Constructor, "new" does nothing good, unless you "return this"; if you don't use the word "this", you don't need the word "new"

Comment: yes sure "this" is the object you create with "new and return this will maintain on independent object " and the not returned, but in that case sum func has reference to the bar func in the foo, it kind of static.